# Javascript links keep breaking due to dynamic directories

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

so I've had this problem before. since the virtual directory is dynamic it keeps breaking my javascript links.
I used ResolveUrl for them and it seemed to have worked.

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/JQueryPlugins/Tooltip/toolitp.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

however, I have ran into a problem. In another file I have another bunch of javascript links that link to javascript files 2 directories up, so the default would look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/yui/utilities/utilities.js"></script>
```

So now when I try to add ResolveUrl to it, it doesn't seem to work.Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the answer just to use `ResolveUrl` in all cases?  If the virtual directory is variable, then you can never use relative links in the HTML page.

Comment: I've tried it but when I run it, it complains that it cannot find the files